# How can I change the backend of Keras dynamically?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, theano

***Preliminary information:** The answers given for the previously asked related questions (e.g., [How to change the backend of Keras to Theano?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47153429/how-to-change-the-backend-of-keras-to-theano), [How to switch Backend with Keras (from TensorFlow to Theano)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42177658/how-to-switch-backend-with-keras-from-tensorflow-to-theano)) did not work for me. Hence, I've created my own question.*

As the title clearly describes, I need to change the backend of `Keras` dynamically (per run). How can I do this? I'm using `Python 3`.

Here is a function that I've created through the feedback on the web:

```
from keras import backend as K
from importlib import reload


def set_keras_backend(backend):
    if K.backend() != backend:
        os.environ['KERAS_BACKEND'] = backend
        reload(K)
        assert K.backend() == backend
```

When I call the function above such as `set_keras_backend('theano')`, getting an assertion error as follows:

```
AssertionError: assert K.backend() == backend
```

p.s. (1) I'm using `macOS Catalina 10.15.5`.

(2) The versions of `TensorFlow`, and `Keras` are `2.2.0`, and `2.4.3`, respectively, which are the most recent stable versions.

(3) The package for the *Theano*, namely `Theano`, was already installed through the `pip`.

Comment: Keras version 2.3.0-tf indicates it is actually tf.keras, not keras, are you sure your code is using that version?

Comment: Yes, these were taken from the console output. First, I've installed the `tensorflow` package, then I've installed the `keras` package through the `pip`. Anything wrong here? @Dr.Snoopy

Comment: How did you print the keras version?

Comment: Here it is: @Dr.Snoopy
`import tensorflow.keras as keras
print(f'Keras version: {keras.__version__}')`

Comment: If I use Keras directly, getting the Keras version as `2.4.3`. @Dr.Snoopy

Comment: That is exactly what I am talking about, you are printing the version of tf.keras. Keras and tf.keras are not the same library, tf.keras only supports TensorFlow as the backend.

Comment: Thanks for that, but the error still happens (I've changed the import of Keras). @Dr.Snoopy